# SSRS: data split in multiple columns, how to indicate it?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

This question is more cosmetic that technical.

I have a report that splits the data in 1 to 4 tablix (all tablix are the same but certain rows are hidden for each tablix depending on the # of rows) to make better use of the paper space. If I have 2 tablix in the same page, I would like to tell the person reading it go from the last row of tablix  1 to the first row in tablix 2, but I'm not sure if there is any "standardised" way to do it.

Example:

```
tablix 1 | tablix 2 | tablix 3 | tablix 4
-row 1-  | -row 5-  | -row 9-  | -row 13-
-row 2-  | -row 6-  | -row 10- | -row 14-
-row 3-  | -row 7-  | -row 11- | -row 15-
-row 4-  | -row 8-  | -row 12- | -row 16-
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just add a note in a textbox in the report header.

Comment: I ended adding a 1/x on the table header, x being the number of tablix I split the data into.